# Can a moderator view my real location/country name in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, moderators, moderator-abilities

Can a moderator of spanish.stackexchange or other network view my real location/country  in my stackoverflow profile?

Answer (score 9):

Yes they can, if you told it to them, or if the IP address you use to access the sites reveals location data (which is sometimes the case and sometimes not, although you can usually infer at least the country.)

A SE employee explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637/245360) what a moderator can see:

> - real name*
> - email*
> - how many days you visited the site (and your current consecutive visits streak)
> - your IP address*
> - all the names you used in the last 90 days
>
> *mods have to click a link to see this information, the act of which is also logged.

Comment: Technically the answer should be *No, unless you told them and then it is viewable by everyone* but I agree the IP address could be give away.